# How to incrementally count each different value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have the following df

```
  val
0  x
1  x
2  z
3  y
4  x
5  y
6  y
7  z
8  x
9  z
```

I would like to create a new column that keeps track of the count for each value incrementally, like so

```
  val  new
0  x   x1
1  x   x2
2  z   z1
3  y   y1
4  x   x3
5  y   y2
6  y   y3
7  z   z2
8  x   x4
9  z   z3
```

I tried using `count()`, but that just counted the total and not incrementally. `value_counts()` does the same, but just split by values, and not incrementally. Is there a simple way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your input dataframe:

```py
df["new"] = df["val"] + df.groupby("val")["val"].cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Outputs:

```py
  val new
0   x  x1
1   x  x2
2   z  z1
3   y  y1
4   x  x3
5   y  y2
6   y  y3
7   z  z2
8   x  x4
9   z  z3
```